# Assign a constant integer to existing newly inserted values

Tags: postgresql, create-table, sequence-generators

I'm looking for an intelligent sequence generator that will be able to assign a constant int value to a column if a string column values exists in the table already. The scenario is as below

```
_____________________________
|   Col1  |  Col2  |  Col 3 |
|---------------------------|
|    a    |    a   |    1   |
|    b    |    a   |    1   |
|    c    |    a   |    1   |
|    u    |    b   |    2   |
|    v    |    b   |    2   |
|    w    |    b   |    2   |
-----------------------------
```

Let's say I insert another value which is ('d','a') to Col1 & Col2 respectively, I want Col3 to become '1' automatically as the Col3 value corresponding to 'a' already exists as '1' and become as seen below

```
_____________________________
|   Col1  |  Col2  |  Col 3 |
|---------------------------|
|    a    |    a   |    1   |
|    b    |    a   |    1   |
|    c    |    a   |    1   |
|    u    |    b   |    2   |
|    v    |    b   |    2   |
|    w    |    b   |    2   |
|    d    |    a   |    1   |
------------------------------
```

Is there a way I can define it in 'Create Table' so that the Col3 value update happens upon value insertion into Col1, Col2?

*Edit :*

The scenario is something like this

```
______________________________________________________________
|   Col1                           |    Col2        |  Col 3 |
|------------------------------------------------------------|
|    Adobe                         |    Adobe       |    1   |
|    Adobe Systems                 |    Adobe       |    1   |
|    Adobe Systems Inc             |    Adobe       |    1   |
|    Honeywell                     |    Honeywell   |    2   |
|    Honeywell Inc                 |    Honeywell   |    2   |
|    Honeywell Inc.                |    Honeywell   |    2   |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

And when I add new data, I would like it to be

```
______________________________________________________________
|   Col1                           |    Col2        |  Col 3 |
|------------------------------------------------------------|
|    Adobe                         |    Adobe       |    1   |
|    Adobe Systems                 |    Adobe       |    1   |
|    Adobe Systems Inc             |    Adobe       |    1   |
|    Honeywell                     |    Honeywell   |    2   |
|    Honeywell Inc                 |    Honeywell   |    2   |
|    Honeywell Inc.                |    Honeywell   |    2   |
|    Adobe Systems Incorporated    |    Adobe       |    1   |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

The Col3 value has to be an integer for faster joins with other tables. I will insert values for Col1 & Col2, and the corresponding value should be available in Col3 upon insert.

Comment: So you want Col3 to always directly correspond to Col2, but be a numeric value?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, there are a few ways I can think of to accomplish it, but they all seem kind of ridiculous. I.e. why have two columns which are *always* identical? (There are valid reasons for doing this, but they're usually pretty advanced use cases). Can you explain maybe a bit more of  your larger goal, in case there's a better way to accomplish it?

Comment: What you need could be done using a trigger. You didn't specify the exact conditions which should be met to update the Col3 and with which value (eg. does it increment and when), thus I can not provide you with an answer.

Comment: Added additional data, and if a new value occurs in Col2, the Col3 value should be incremental integer.

Comment: You can easily generate that number when you retrieve the data: `dense_rank() over (partition by col2 order by col2)`

Answer (score 3):

Just normalize it:

```
create table corporation (
    corporation_id serial,
    short_name text
);

insert into corporation (short_name) values
('Adobe'),('Honeywell');

select * from corporation;
 corporation_id | short_name 
----------------+------------
              1 | Adobe
              2 | Honeywell
```

Now you table is:

```
|    Adobe                         |    1
|    Adobe Systems                 |    1
|    Adobe Systems Inc             |    1
|    Honeywell                     |    2
|    Honeywell Inc                 |    2
|    Honeywell Inc.                |    2
|    Adobe Systems Incorporated    |    1
```

Answer (score 0):

> The Col3 value has to be an integer for faster joins with other
>   tables.

So you need unique, but not necessarily sequential, values. You can use a hash function to map strings into unique integers, e. g.:

```
postgres=# select hashtext('Adobe');
 hashtext  
-----------
 173079840
(1 row)

postgres=# select hashtext('Honeywell');
  hashtext  
------------
 -453308048
(1 row)
```

With such a function, you avoid the need to lookup existing values in the table.

But are you really sure you will have performance problems using strings for foreign keys? You should test it on your data, I think. (Also test on upcoming 9.5, with its [abbreviated keys](http://pgeoghegan.blogspot.ru/2015/01/abbreviated-keys-exploiting-locality-to.html) feature.)

Comment: `hashtext` is not documented and its behavior can change.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto Well, one can use md5 or something like that, but normalization is way better, you are right.